# How to extract all the http request's tcp sequence numer with tshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, pcap, tshark

For some research reason, I need to get the http package's tcp sequence numbers. I have already got the pcap file, so how should I do that with tshark?

Thanks so much for answer my question!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
tshark -r your_file -R http -T fields -e tcp.seq
```

The sequence numbers are relative or absolute as controlled by .wireshark/preferences. By default it's relative (so you will see small numbers). If you want absolute sequence numbers, edit `preferences`:

```
tcp.relative_sequence_numbers: FALSE
```

Answer (score -1):

Using tshark,

apply the correspoding tcp filter (tcp.nxtseq) check for more from this page 
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html

```
C:\Program Files\Wireshark>tshark -r C:<path to pcap>sample.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.flags.ack -e tcp.flags.cwr -e tcp.flags.ecn -e tcp.flags.fin -e tcp.flags.ns -e tcp.flags.push -e tcp.flags.res -e tcp.flags.reset -e tcp.flags.syn -e tcp.flags.urg > C:/20Oct.txt
```